# Почему пишут const когда можно написать let?

Tags: javascript, константа

Я иногда вижу, что пишут `const` (значение этой переменной я знаю), хотя можно просто написать `let`. Это что, просто особенность "подчерка"?

Вот пример:

```
const prev = document.querySelector(".btn_prev");
const next = document.querySelector(".btn_next");

let prev = document.querySelector(".btn_prev");
let next = document.querySelector(".btn_next");
```

Ну зачем кнопки брать в `const`?

Что `const` не изменяемая, это я знаю.

Comment: @Air `let` короче, а настоящий программист должен быть ленивым!) Если честно, тоже не понимаю, почему злоупотребляют const везде, где переменная не должна менять значение... на данный момент использую его только там, где это правда константа, или важная переменная, которая не входит в блок кода, и о котором можно спустя 2000 строк забыть. А таких практически не бывает)

Comment: Это чтобы ты спустя 100500 строк не записал в ```prev``` или ```next``` что-то другое, к примеру дату, а потом не удивлялся, почему у неё нет события ```onclick```.

Comment: Я бы немного расширил вопрос (хотя, возможно, могут закрыть, как "зависит от мнений"): Когда правильно писать const, а когда let. И это касается и переменных и function expression и **действительно констант типа ERROR_CANT_READ** и других моментов

Comment: const - это как подсказка программисту, что данная переменная не должна перезаписываться. Так удобнее писать\понимать код.

Comment: Чтобы когда ты вдруг случайно попытаешь переопределить переменную в будущем(а спустя много строчек кода ты обязательно забудешь о ней), ты увидел синтаксическую ошибку, и не искал потом много времени в коде логическую ошибку, почему все работает не так, как ожидалось. Это экономит твое, и чужое время. Как писали выше так надежнее.

Comment: const не толлько для програмиста, но и для сборщика, в случае единичного использования. Например 
```const a=123;console.log(a);```
может быть собрано как 
```console.log(123)```
так же const дает возможность оптимизировать рантайм немного

Comment: Данные не изменяются - const. Изменяются - let. Я наоборот когда вижу let, это сбивает с толку, потому что ищу место, где переменная должна измениться, а она неизменяемая

Comment: Тем более если к проекту подключён eslint например, то он будет выдавать предупреждение за let, где необходим const

Comment: Если какой либо ответ вас устроил, примите его.

Answer (score 6):

1) Добавляет читаемости коду (хоть какой то порядок пытаемся навести в анархичном JS)

А умение разбираться в чужом коде - это очень хороший навык. И если сразу увидишь `const` то будешь уверен, что нигде ссылка не переписывается дальше по коду. И я думаю, что следующий программер который будет разбираться в коде скажет спасибо, если будет все интуитивно понятно.

2) Самому закладывать логику кода удобнее

Когда ты сам понимаешь, как должна работать твоя функция, то и легко определить где значение должно быть железно определено и неизменяемо, а где будет действительно переменное значение переменной (классная тавтология)

PS. [Нашел](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-var-let-%D0%B8-const-%D0%B2-javascript-3084bfe9f7a3) краткое резюме отличий между var, let и const:

```
var: 
  // function scoped (область видимости ограничивается функцией)
  // undefined when accessing a variable before it's declared (при обращении вернет undefined)
let: 
  // block scoped (область видимости ограничивается блоком  {} )
  // ReferenceError when accessing a variable before it's declared (при обращении выдаст ReferenceError)
const:
  // block scoped (область видимости ограничивается блоком  {} )
  // ReferenceError when accessing a variable before it's declared (при обращении выдаст ReferenceError)
  // can't be reassigned (невозможно переопределить)
```

Comment: А правильно ли я понимаю, что при `function expression` в таком случае надо использовать всегда `const`?

Comment: @СергейМишин на мой взгляд это было бы логично. Все зависит от логики кода

Comment: Это русскоязычное сообщество, прошу прокомментировать на русском языке описание к  `var`, `let`,  `const`. И можно приложить пруфы.

Comment: @doox911 - читайте внимательнее, в скобках все прокомментировано - подробнее в ссылке

Comment: Так вы подправили ответ)))

Comment: Добавил ссылку на первоисточник

Comment: Кстати `can't be reassigned (невозможно переопределить)` - не совсем правда. Потому что даже если мы напишем `const` для объекта `const test = {key1: 1, key2: 2}`, то его значения всё равно можно переопределить и даже добавлять новые, пока не применишь на нём `Object.freeze( )`. С массивами тоже, кстати

Comment: @СергейМишин - const подразумевает что сама ссылка не будет переопределена, свойства менять можно, все верно.

Answer (score 0):

если говорить практично, то const используют один раз и более не переназначают это значение, в отличии от let которым можно назначить, а потом ещё раз.

Пример:
1) const = user

2) let = user
Далее где-то, можем сделать так:
let = user + user2